# Android Studio - Cant run script in external tool

Tags: android, adb

I cant run a script in my Android Studio, using external tool.

Its giving me

> /Users/me/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb: adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app
> adb: unknown command adb

but when I try to run `adb devices` anywhere, in any terminal, its working fine..

Does anyone know how to fix it?

**EDIT**

Looking to the error response:

**/Users/me/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb:** -> (path where script is running in terminal)

**adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app** -> script itself

**adb: unknown command adb** -> Error

Here is how I'm using the external tool
[image]

Comment: What happens if you just type `adb shell` ?

Comment: @Alex same error. I tried `adb devices` too

Comment: @LMaker  just remove "adb:" . For using adb commands you don't need write adb: adb shell. just write adb shell...

Comment: Please clarify what is the script you're trying to run? Can you show this script in your question? And how exactly do you use "external tools"?

Comment: @AlirezABarakati what? "adb:" is part of the path where the script is running....

Comment: @Vadik look at my edits pls

Comment: I think your problem is you adding the whole command to the field "Arguments". `adb` or `/full/path/to/the/adb` — is the command ("Program"), `shell setprop ...` — are "Arguments". See answer from Alex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have double adb based on your updated post.

In the external tools editor, where you add the Arguments make sure that you don't have `adb` in that line.

The argument has to be only `shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app` without adb since you define the adb in the "Program" section